# After closing workbook in different application some instance remains

Tags: excel, vba

I have to copy data from many Excel files to each another file. The target file has a certain formatting and some functionality, so I have to use a certain file as a template (not .xltx) and cannot create a new file.
My idea is: From my workbook with the marcos I open the source file and the template file in separate application (the user can compare source and target in separate windows), I copy the required data to the template file and save the template file under a different name.
That works quite well. But on the next run I get the

> runtime error 1004 “cannot access [template file name]”.

Obviously not everything was closed during the first run. But I have no idea what that is. In the task manager only my Excel file with the macros is shown.
Whenn I quit my code and start again it works as in the first run.

```
Dim FileChoice As Variant
Dim SourceFileApp As Excel.Application
Dim DestFileApp As Excel.Application
Dim DestFilePath As String
Dim SourceBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim DestBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim actFileNum As Integer
'------------------------------------------------
Sub OpenFiles()

Dim tmpArr As Variant
Dim i As Integer

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'open SourceFile
Set SourceFileApp = New Excel.Application
SourceFileApp.Visible = True 'False
Set SourceBook = SourceFileApp.Workbooks.Add(FileChoice(actFileNum))
'FileChoice: Collection of files form GetOpenFileName

'I couldn't find a way to retrive the FilePath with VBA
'SourceBook.Path is empty
tmpArr = Split(FileChoice(actFileNum), "\")
For i = 0 To UBound(tmpArr) - 1
    DestFilePath = DestFilePath & tmpArr(i) & "\"
Next

'open DestFile
Set DestFileApp = New Excel.Application
DestFileApp.Visible = True 'False
Set DestBook = DestFileApp.Workbooks.Add(DestFilePath & "DestinationFormatFile.xlsx")

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
   MsgBox "Error in Sub OpenFiles"

End Sub

'------------------------------------------------
Sub CloseFiles()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'close SourceFile
SourceFileApp.Workbooks(1).Close SaveChanges:=False
SourceFileApp.Quit
Set SourceBook = Nothing
Set SourceFileApp = Nothing

'close DestFile
DestFileApp.Workbooks(1).SaveAs (DestFilePath & "DestinationFormatFile" & Str(actFileNum) & ".xlsx")
DestFileApp.Workbooks(1).Close SaveChanges:=False
DestFileApp.Quit
Set DestBook = Nothing
Set DestFileApp = Nothing

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
   MsgBox "Error in Sub CloseFile"

End Sub
```

Comment: What `FileChoice` does contain? How was it filled? Your code doesn't show anything regarding the way was filled. Why do you use `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler` since the code does not work as expected? This option does not let you to properly debug. I would comment it and then I would run the code line by line, using F8 and see if something wrong happens, in which line...

Comment: FileChoice is the array given by Application.GetOpenFilename, MultiSelect:=True.
Be sure that On Error GoTo is switched off when debugging. The error is raised in the line: Set DestBook = DestFileApp.Workbooks.Add(DestFilePath & "DestinationFormatFile.xlsx")". As far as I see runtime error 1004 isn't raised by my code but by Excel because something is obviously in use.

Comment: Then, you must understand Why a workbook with the same name is open in a hidden (probably) Excel session. Please kill (using Task Manger) all Excel sessions and then try the code again, without any error handling, running the code line by line, using F8. Separate of all that, where `Application.GetOpenFilename` does fill the `FileChoice`? Are you sure that is that happening in the same session? I can see the new session is created during this piece of code... Does `GetOpenFilename` only fills the workbooks array, or already opens a workbook?

Comment: Does `GetOpenFilename` only fills the workbooks array, or already opens a workbook? In this regards, I would fill the array during the  code, just before the problematic code line.

Comment: I tried it out step by step and followed the task manager. Now I open the files by the original path and file name, not via the fileopen-dialog. As expected the task manger opens 3 Excel-application entries, one of the entries with the original file name of the file I use as template. In the closing routine the template file is renamed by  DestFileApp.Workbooks(1).SaveAs and in the task manager the name change.So it seems as if in the following the renamed workbook ist closed, the application as well, but the original file name of the template file is still remaining.

Comment: Do you all the time have a single open file in one session? If not, `DestFileApp.Workbooks(1)` may not refer to the same workbook...

Comment: Yes, I have.
After renaming the template file DestFileApp.Workbooks(1) is "DestinationFormatFile", after DestFileApp.Workbooks(1).Close DestFileApp.Workbooks.Count = 0

Comment: May be I got it. When I replace in "DestFileApp.Workbooks(1).SaveAs (DestFilePath & "DestinationFormatFile" & Str(actFileNum) & ".xlsx")" the variable DestFilePath by the original Path in text everthing seems to work fine.
I'll check ist out and I'll report. Thank you very much for the moment.

Comment: I have to apologize for my mistake. Unexpectedly the path to the template file was emptied. So of course the template file could not be found for the next run . I should have seen that myself. But I thank you very much for your methodical help with debugging.